# How to sub-thread a long process in a web-request in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a function which pulls data from other websites which takes up to 30 seconds to complete. I need this function to execute on a web request from a user but don't want him to wait that time.

Currently the method is called from within my view-controller.

How can I have that method execute on his own time rather than have the user wait?

Comment: if the response you want to show the user depends on the long process, the answer is different

Comment: True, but this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the response you want to show the user does not depend on the outcome of your long process then all you need to do is execute the process in a thread different from the main request.

You can certainly take Steve's approach and use a processing queue (delayed_job, sidekiq, resque) but this sounds like overkill. You can simply fork a new [subprocess](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-fork) and detach it or fork a new [thread](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-c-fork)

```
pid = Process.fork do 
  long_process
end
Process.detach pid
```

Comment: I know this has already been accepted as the answer, but it's not. There are many ways that this can go wrong. The server might kill your process. Your process and the master process might both try to use the same database connection for transactions at the same time, etc. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984748/process-fork-in-rails-controller .

Comment: true, it has its dangers, but how can the server kill it and what is the problem with shared db connection. would you mind elaborating? I see a hint in your link about AR and fork but not sure if it is uptodate worry.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this subject, but I don't need to be. Rails does not specifically support forking, and therefore, we cannot predict that should work even if we did not know of specific issues with that. As it is, we know that a load balancer could shut down a Rails process, thus closing resources the fork is still using, and we know that if a shared database connection happens to work at all, one process could end up executing statements within a transaction created by the other, leading to incorrect results and/or errors. I'm sure there is a vast array of other potential issues

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a background agent that processes these requests. I recently implemented something like this using the beaneater gem and beanstalkd for a message queue. I used the God Gem to manage that background process, and wrote an init script to manage the God process. JavaScript in the page makes AJAX calls every 1.5 seconds to query the status of the request and tell the user when it is done.

I subsequently learned that God is known to have a memory leak, so Bluepill might be a better choice. Just today, I also found http://michaelvanrooijen.com/articles/2011/06/08-managing-and-monitoring-your-ruby-application-with-foreman-and-upstart/ which describes using Foreman and Upstart for background processes, and this seems like a more straightforward and robust approach. Next time I need to do this kind of thing, I'll probably try Foreman/Upstart/beaneater/beanstalkd.

Note that there are many different message queues to choose from with different strengths and weaknesses. beanstalkd is very responsive, which is nice for running processes that take minutes or less.